# Calling between viewmodels (KnockOutJS)

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, viewmodel, knockout-viewmodel-plugin

I'm using KnockoutJS to develop a plugin based on viewmodels. Is there any way to access the functions and properties of another viewmodel running in the same application? Something like this:

*My view model:*

```
    function myViewModel()
    {
        this.prop1 = ko.observable(123);
        this.prop2 = ko.observable("Hello");
        ..
        ..
    }

    myViewModel.prototype.func1 = function() {
        //do something...
    };

    myViewModel.prototype.func2 = function() {
        //do something...
    };
```

*And the other view model:*

```
    function otherViewModel()
    {
        this.propA = ko.observable(456);
        this.propB = ko.observable("Goodbye");
        ..
        ..
    }

    otherViewModel.prototype.funcA = function() {
        //do something...
    };

    otherViewModel.prototype.funcB = function() {
        //do something...
    };
```

The observables of the ***otherViewModel*** control certain common functions like pop-ups and masks. Is there any way to instantiate ***otherViewModel*** in ***myViewModel*** and set those properties?

Or is there any way to globally get and set them?

Please tread lightly as I'm very new to this paradigm. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, this is a *very* broad question. You should read about closures, scopes, and oo-style JS programming. For a more practical approach, carefully go through [the knockoutjs tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) as well as the documenation. There are many examples in there where dependencies are created between view models.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment to use scopes - but there are a couple of quick and dirty ways...

when you instantiate myViewModel - you could instantiate it on the window - and then reference it directly

```
window.myViewInstance = new myViewModel()

function myOtherViewModel () {
  this.propA = myViewInstance.xyz
}
```

I use this method when I have something that provides global functionality that I want to use elsewhere.  Its what jQuery and ko do... bind $ and ko to the window.

if myViewModel.xyz = ko.observable() then passing it without parens passes it as an observable - which will change as its value changes.  With the parens will pass the result at the time it is evaluated.

Alternatively - you can reference it using ko.dataFor like this.

```
myViewModel () {...}
instance = new myViewModel
ko.applyBindings(instance, $('div')[0])
// this applies bindings of myViewModel to the first div on the page only

myOtherViewModel () {

  this.propA = ko.dataFor($('div')[0])
  // passes the entire object
  this.propB = ko.dataFor($('div')[0]).xyz
  // gives you just one property

}
```

Which would scope your object to just a part of the page

Comment: I found a much better solution here: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox